# How to use InternalsVisibleTo without creating a circular reference

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

My understanding of `InternalsVisibleTo` is that it is primarily for unit-testing. But that means that my unit test class, if it's in a separate project, needs a reference to the project that has the class with `InternalsVisibleTo`, and also *that* class needs a reference to the unit test class in order to get its assembly name to put in the parameter of the attribute.

How to solve this Catch-22?

Comment: Assembly under test (with the class you're testing) does not need a reference to the UT assembly. It just has to mention it's **name** in `[InternalsVisibleTo]`.

Comment: What Catch-22? Did you try it? You don't need a reference to the unit test assembly just to get its name. You know the name of the assembly...just pass _that_ to the attribute. If you are having trouble getting to work, it's because you're doing it wrong, not because there's a mandatory circular reference. If you can't figure it out, post a new question that includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, explain exactly what you've tried to fix it, and what _specifically_ is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following project structure.

You have a project named `Company.Org.PersonManager`, building an assembly named

```
Company.Org.PersonManager.dll
```

It contains the following class declaration

```
internal class Person
{
    public string Foo();
}
```

If you want to test the Foo method, you might write a nunit test in a project named `Company.Org.PersonManager.Test`

The implementation could look something like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestPersonManager
{
    [Test]
    public void Test_Foo()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        Assert(p .... );
    }
}
```

The above code will not compile because the Person class is only internally visible in assembly `Company.Org.PersonManager.dll`

This is where `InternalsVisibleTo`come in handy, if you add the following line

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Company.Org.PersonManager.Test.dll")]
```

to `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs` in the project `Company.Org.PersonManager`, you are telling the compiler that the assembly 
`Company.Org.PersonManager.Test.dll` has access to internal classes and methods in the assembly `Company.Org.PersonManager.dll`

This should not result in a circular reference, the `Company.Org.PersonManager.Test` should have a reference to `Company.Org.PersonManager`, but no other references should be neccesary.